# SAS EG Local submit

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

```
rsubmit;
  <Code>
endrsubmit;
```

This is useful if u are connected to the local server and you want to run a code on the remote. But how do I run a local script from the remote server? Is there something equivalent to `localsubmit`?

**Additional Info:**

I run most of my codes on the remote server because it is faster but I need to use the local SAS in two instances

- There is one location with lots of space that I am unable to access through the remote server. I.e. it can be accessed as `I:\folder1\folder2` but not as `/folder1/folder2` (I tried finding a shortcut through filezilla but I guess the IT team has not created it)
- `Proc export` with `dbms = excel` is only possible with a local server without which I cannot export multiple data in the same excel file (Which leads to a mess and would involve changing set processes/architecture that use `dbms = excel`)

Comment: Do you really need to use `excel` engine instead of the `xlsx` engine?  If so have you tried using SAS PC Files server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run code locally (on the machine on which EG installed) if you have a Base SAS licence.  You will know this is the case if you open your SAS program (in EG), and check the values in the "Selected Server" dropdown.  If you have a 'local' option you can run locally.

There is no concept of `localsubmit`.  If you wanted to run code on your machine and trigger it from the server, your local machine would have to be configured as a SAS/Connect server and you would use `rsubmit` (with appropriate connection profile) from that server to your local machine.  This would be a highly unusual scenario!

Comment: I don't understand why it would be an unusual scenario though!. I've added some context in the question to explain why I was looking for it. But this is a smart workaround

Comment: it would be unusual for a remote SAS server to `rsubmit` to a local desktop, as typically it would be unnecessary - the process is easier to trigger _from_ the desktop

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly, at least for the second example there's a fairly common use case here.

What you'd do is to run the main program in rsubmit, and then in non-rsubmit block download the dataset created from the rsubmit block.

```
libname rwork slibref=work server=<yourserver>;
```

See [this KB article](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/836.html) for more information.

Then you could do it easily:

```
rsubmit server=myserver;
  data class;
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
endrsubmit;

libref rwork slibref=work server=myserver;

data l_class;
  set rwork.class;
run;

proc export data=l_class ...;
run;
```

Or even skip the `l_class` dataset and directly export from `rwork`.

For the first scenario, a large part depends on why you can't just *not* use rsubmit.  Is the program located on the remote server, and you can't directly access it?  You'd want to talk to IT I guess to find out how to directly access it.

Comment: I do use this to share libraries across servers and this is the kind of code that I use currently. Its just that 90% of my code and I have been coding in SAS for a while now. I just thought it might be simpler if only the code that needs to run on the local can somehow be separated and run in a special way, rather than trying to run everything except that using `rsubmit`

Comment: I think that's what I'm suggesting: put the part of your code you want to run locally outside of RSUBMIT, and use the rwork library to transfer data back and forth.  Don't do so too often since it's likely slow to transfer from one to the other, but one time or two times is fine.

Comment: Essentially: `<code> rsubmit; <code> endrsubmit; <code> `.

Comment: Yes I understand, but 3 things annoy me with the `rsubmit` architecture (other than the limitations mentioned in the question). 1) If a big block of code is running on `rsubmit` it takes a long time to abort. Killing codes is much faster when you are directly running them on the remote instead of `rsubmit` from the local. 2) The log comes up in every step as well when you run on the remote server but the `rsubmit` log comes up only when the submit is complete 3) If u want to run something step by step u need to either use shortcuts or keep encasing the code in `rsubmit`